# Create a View of Group Posts Who's Group has a Specific Tax Term?

Tags: views, organic-groups

Hi i hope someone can help me get my head about this. I dont know if im just having a blonde moment though.

I have tax terms added to my 'groups' (blog, betting, diary etc) I was wanting to create a view showing just posts in Groups that have the term 'blog' attached to the Group. The posts in Groups tagged with 'blog' do not have the term 'blog' in the posts so thus they will not show in any views i create. I hope im making sense here as i think im just confusing the issue.

I think i would need some sort of Relationship to create the View Ill try explain again. I only have one Group content type 'Groups'. Each group has a term (blog, betting etc) I want to...bah im just saying the same thing again arent i?...How can i show just my 'Group Posts' whos parent Group is tagged with 'betting' in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your view configuration, you need to set up a group node relationship and filter out group nodes by taxonomy term. This should do it for you:

**Add relationship:** Organic groups: Group node (post)
**Require this relationship:** checked

**Add filter:** Taxonomy: Term
**Vocabulary:** Your Vocabulary
**Selection type:** Dropdown
**Relationship:** Group node (post)
**Operator:** Is one of
**Select terms from vocabulary Your Vocabulary:** blog

Comment: Sorry for the delay in commenting Jan. Ive been travelling back from a trip to asia. Why am i coming back? As i want to work on my drupal site lol. Thats cracking Jan thanks. Spot on for what i am after. This opens up so many possibilities for me. Thanks for all your help :)